# gnuplot - printing multiple plots from one dataset in same file as script

Tags: gnuplot

Ive this script in gnuplot and I want to print multiple plots from 1 dataset. Ive tried this command but it seems that command needs another sama dataset to execute this command correctly. Do you know how to solve it?

```
plot '-' using 1:2, '=' using 1:3
1 1 5
2 2 5
3 3 5
e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `'-'` you would have to enter the same data again. Check `help special-filenames`.

You better do:

```
$Data <<EOD
1 1 5
2 2 5
3 3 5
EOD

plot $Data u 1:2, '' u 1:3
```